# Switch statement returning undefined

Tags: javascript

```
function getLetter(s) {
    let letter = s[0];
    // Write your code here
    let A = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
    let B = ['b','c','d','f','g'];
    let C = ['h','j','k','l','m'];
    let D = ['n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z'];

  switch(letter) {
    case A.includes(s.charAt(0)): 
      return 'A';
    break;

    case B.includes(s.charAt(0)): 
      return 'B';
    break;

    case C.includes(s.charAt(0)): 
      return 'C';
    break;

    case D.includes(s.charAt(0)): 
        return 'D';
    break;
  }
}

s = 'adam';
t = getLetter(s);
console.log(t);
```

I'm learning switches and I'm trying this problem where I'm supposed to pass in a string and the function getLetter() is supposed to return 'A' if the first letter of the string is any of the elements in array A. And similar for arrays B,C,D. I tried the code above but it returns undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: basically, you're checking if `letter` (a string) is equal to `A.includes(s.charAt(0))` (a boolean), which is never the case.

Comment: You should use `if`, `else if` here instead of `switch`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: `switch` statement is better if you want to match one value to multiple values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check against a boolean value, like `true`, because you use `includes`, which returns `true` or `false`.

BTW, by using `return` in each `case`, you could omit to `break`, because the function exits with `return`, which exits the [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) as well.

```js
function getLetter(s) {
    let letter = s[0];
    // Write your code here
    let A = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    let B = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g'];
    let C = ['h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'];
    let D = ['n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

    switch (true) { // <-- boolean value with strict comparison ===
        case A.includes(letter):
            return 'A';
        case B.includes(letter):
            return 'B';
        case C.includes(letter):
            return 'C';
        case D.includes(letter):
            return 'D';
    }
}

var s = 'adam',
    t = getLetter(s);

console.log(t);
```

Comment: Thanks. When I did it using an if-statement, it worked fine: ```  if(A.includes(s.charAt(0))) {
      return 'A';
  };``` If I wanted a condition for false, would I have to write another switch statement for the false condition or just return a default parameter outside the switch and inside the function?

Comment: in the case clause, you could negate the value with [logical NOT `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` instead of `includes`, when you pass a character to `switch()` it tries to match that against case, since `includes` return `true/false` so it won't match any case

```js
function getLetter(s) {
  let letter = s[0];
  let A = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  let B = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g'];
  let C = ['h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'];
  let D = ['n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

  switch (letter) {
    case A.find(v => v === letter):
      return 'A';
    case B.find(v => v === letter):
      return 'B';
    case C.find(v => v === letter):
      return 'C';
    case D.find(v => v === letter):
      return 'D';
  }
}

s = 'adam';
t = getLetter(s);
console.log(t);
```